# Converting a dataframe to a 3D tensor (with multiple features)

Tags: python, pandas, keras, lstm, tensor

I'm working on building a model to predict if a forex pair is a buy or sell.
I got a dataframe build up of 64 features and 5000 rows. Every row is 1-day of information (Open,high,low,close) and some indicators as extra features.

I know that keras lstm takes as input shape numpy array (batchsize,#timestepsinonesample,#features). I also know it should be an numpy array as input type.

I'm trying to build a Many-to-One architecture let's say 5 days should predict if the next day is a buy/or sell.
What I need is a function that transforms my dataframe to a 3d tensor, but I just can't figure it out how to build that tensor with the multiple features per day and getting that together with the following timesteps in 1 sample of 5 timesteps. So my tensor dimensions should be (batchsize,5,64)
I've read about every tutorial on the web and every answer here on stack overflow. And I understand what needs to happen but can't write the function.

I tried this:

```
    seq_length = 5
    x = []
    y = []
    for i in range(0, len(features) - seq_length):
    given = features[i:i + seq_length]
    predict = labels[i + seq_length]
    x.append(given)
    y.append(predict)
```

But this outputs a list and I couldn't get it converted to a numpy array.
If someone could help me out how to convert this I've been stuck for a couple of days now on this problem.